# How to handle :java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: android.os.BinderProxy.finalize() timed out after 10 seconds errors?

Tags: android, garbage-collection

We're seeing a number of `TimeoutExceptions` in `GcWatcher.finalize, BinderProxy.finalize`, and `PlainSocketImpl.finalize`.  90+% of them happen on Android 4.3.  We're getting reports of this from Crittercism from users out in the field.

[image]

The error is a variation of: "`com.android.internal.BinderInternal$GcWatcher.finalize() timed out after 10 seconds`"

```
java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: android.os.BinderProxy.finalize() timed out after 10 seconds
at android.os.BinderProxy.destroy(Native Method)
at android.os.BinderProxy.finalize(Binder.java:459)
at java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerDaemon.doFinalize(Daemons.java:187)
at java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerDaemon.run(Daemons.java:170)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
```

So far we haven't had any luck reproducing the problem in house or figuring out what might have caused it.

Any ideas what can cause this?
Any idea how to debug this and find out which part of the app causes this? 
Anything that sheds light on the issue helps.

More Stacktraces:

```
1   android.os.BinderProxy.destroy  
2   android.os.BinderProxy.finalize Binder.java, line 482
3   java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerDaemon.doFinalize    Daemons.java, line 187
4   java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerDaemon.run   Daemons.java, line 170
5   java.lang.Thread.run    Thread.java, line 841
```

2

```
1   java.lang.Object.wait   
2   java.lang.Object.wait   Object.java, line 401
3   java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove ReferenceQueue.java, line 102
4   java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove ReferenceQueue.java, line 73
5   java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerDaemon.run   Daemons.java, line 170
6   java.lang.Thread.run
```

3

```
1   java.util.HashMap.newKeyIterator    HashMap.java, line 907
2   java.util.HashMap$KeySet.iterator   HashMap.java, line 913
3   java.util.HashSet.iterator  HashSet.java, line 161
4   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.interruptIdleWorkers    ThreadPoolExecutor.java, line 755
5   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.interruptIdleWorkers    ThreadPoolExecutor.java, line 778
6   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.shutdown    ThreadPoolExecutor.java, line 1357
7   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.finalize    ThreadPoolExecutor.java, line 1443
8   java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerDaemon.doFinalize    Daemons.java, line 187
9   java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerDaemon.run   Daemons.java, line 170
10  java.lang.Thread.run
```

4

```
1   com.android.internal.os.BinderInternal$GcWatcher.finalize   BinderInternal.java, line 47
2   java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerDaemon.doFinalize    Daemons.java, line 187
3   java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerDaemon.run   Daemons.java, line 170
4   java.lang.Thread.run
```

Comment: Never mind, found it https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=864102 I can also confirm is affecting our apps, it smells like a Google Play Services issue

Comment: The line of code which the error is thrown was introduced Version 4.3_r1, which was release in 5 June 2013. Might be the problem is happening since then.

Comment: Android version 4.2.2 also started to throw this exception so maybe its a google play update that is the source.

Comment: @EvelioTarazona I have it in some app that does not use play-services

Comment: @ligi is it the same stack-trace for you?

Comment: Little bit late, not sure if you have fixed (or worked around) this? When there is some native code to clean up resources this is called by the GC - however most classes with heavy native back-ends also expose a close/release type of method - maybe you have missed calling that somewhere - if you call it in app then there is no 10 second kill-off point.

Comment: Any news about this issue? I am getting a lot of errors of this kind, and they only happen on Samsung devices with 4.4.2 (more than 100 users).

Comment: What web tool / service are you using to collect exception details ?

Comment: Does anyone know if the app actually crashes when this occurs? I occasionally get some crash / error logs which don't actually kill the app, so I'm hoping this is one of them since there's not much we can do about it

Answer (score 249):

**Full disclosure** - I'm the author of the previously mentioned talk in TLV DroidCon.

I had a chance to examine this issue across many Android applications, and discuss it with other developers who encountered it - and we all got to the same point: this issue cannot be avoided, only minimized.

I took a closer look at the default implementation of the Android Garbage collector code, to understand better why this exception is thrown and on what could be the possible causes. I even found a possible root cause during experimentation.

The root of the problem is at the point a device "Goes to Sleep" for a while - this means that the OS has decided to lower the battery consumption by stopping most User Land processes for a while, and turning Screen off, reducing CPU cycles, etc. The way this is done - is on a Linux system level where the processes are Paused mid run. This can happen at any time during normal Application execution, but it will stop at a Native system call, as the context switching is done on the kernel level. So - this is where the Dalvik GC joins the story.

The Dalvik GC code (as implemented in the Dalvik project in the AOSP site) is not a complicated piece of code. The basic way it work is covered in my DroidCon slides. What I did not cover is the basic GC loop - at the point where the collector has a list of Objects to finalize (and destroy). The loop logic at the base can be simplified like this:

1. take `starting_timestamp`,
2. remove object for list of objects to release,
3. release object - `finalize()` and call native `destroy()` if required,
4. take `end_timestamp`,
5. calculate (`end_timestamp - starting_timestamp`) and compare against a hard coded timeout value of 10 seconds,
6. if timeout has reached - throw the `java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException` and kill the process.

### Now consider the following scenario:

Application runs along doing its thing.

This is not a user facing application, it runs in the background.

During this background operation, objects are created, used and need to be collected to release memory.

Application does not bother with a WakeLock - as this will affect the battery adversely, and seems unnecessary.

This means the Application will invoke the GC from time to time.

Normally the GC runs is completed without a hitch.

Sometimes (very rarely) the system will decide to sleep in the middle of the GC run.

This will happen if you run your application long enough, and monitor the Dalvik memory logs closely.

Now - consider the timestamp logic of the basic GC loop - it is possible for the device to start the run, take a `start_stamp`, and go to sleep at the `destroy()` native call on a system object.

When it wakes up and resumes the run, the `destroy()` will finish, and the next `end_stamp` will be the time it took the `destroy()` call + the sleep time.

If the sleep time was long (more than 10 seconds), the `java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException` will be thrown.

I have seen this in the graphs generated from the analysis python script - for Android System Applications, not just my own monitored apps.

Collect enough logs and you will eventually see it.

### Bottom line:

The issue cannot be avoided - you will encounter it if your app runs in the background.

You can mitigate by taking a WakeLock, and prevent the device from sleeping, but that is a different story altogether, and a new headache, and maybe another talk in another con.

You can minimize the problem by reducing GC calls - making the scenario less likely (tips are in the slides).

I have not yet had the chance to go over the Dalvik 2 (a.k.a ART) GC code - which boasts a new Generational Compacting feature, or performed any experiments on an Android Lollipop.

**Added 7/5/2015:**

After reviewing the Crash reports aggregation for this crash type, it looks like these crashes from version 5.0+ of Android OS (Lollipop with ART) only account for 0.5% of this crash type. This means that the ART GC changes has reduced the frequency of these crashes.

**Added 6/1/2016:**

Looks like the Android project has added a lot of info on how the GC works in Dalvik 2.0 (a.k.a ART).

You can read about it here - [Debugging ART Garbage Collection](https://source.android.com/devices/tech/dalvik/gc-debug.html).

It also discusses some tools to get information on the GC behavior for your app.

Sending a SIGQUIT to your app process will essentially cause an ANR, and dump the application state to a log file for analysis.

Comment: In my case, I'm also planning to try to mitigate this by finding ways to reduce the amount of code/time I'm running in the background. Thanks for your research on the topic.

Comment: removing any background processing done in your app will greatly help reduce the problem.

Comment: For what it is worth, this happens still in Marshmallow (6.0.1). That said, I have only ever received this error once. So it doesn't seem to be a gigantic problem. Thank you for your thorough explanation.

Comment: After some time, I got the distinct impression that fixing this problem in the OS is very problematic, and requires cooperation between Google and the OEMs. I do not expect this to be fixed any time soon.

Comment: I'm using wakelock but still encountered this issue on Android 4.4.2. My app has some background operations but mainly designed to work all day long while charge cable mounted. Is there any different way to mitigate this issue?

Comment: Not one that I found. Your scenario meets the criteria of this issue: an app  has a long running background operation that generates garbage. You cannot avoid it using a wakelock, only reduce the frequency. The reason is that the GC event can happen after you release your wakelock, and there is no way to force the System to perform GC before. unless you hold a wakelock forever....

Comment: Assume that i'm fine with wakelock increasing my battery consumption. Can i prevent this issue if i hold the wakelock forever.(But i guess if GC operation takes time it will timeout anyway, but what if it happens due to sleep thing. will wakelock solve the problem). ?

Comment: If the device will never sleep, this problem will be solved. You will have other problems though - like running out of power eventually. If you are dealing with a device with constant power supply, you can try this approach. if you can - tell me if it worked!

Comment: So this issue still exists even on Android 6.0.1 , and there is no good way to handle this? I've decided to create a new bug report here: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=212914

Comment: ART has reduced the frequency of this issue - due to reduced GC runs overall. Solving the problem requires the GC to be aware of the Global CPU state changes, for *each* ART process running in the system. Even if the Android team can somehow solve it, Vendors can freely change it as they see fit. Actually - certain Vendors use a aggressive power saving methods, causing the issue to surface more often.

Comment: @oba If I will no release any objects while my background work and will do this only on foreground and will call GC after this? Or even don't release memory in background + sleep mode? Could it help?

Comment: @MaxF I don't understand the comment. The problem will only happen when the app is on the background, and device goes to sleep (screen off). can you explain what you meant?

Comment: @oba if GC on its start haven't objects for clean maybe it will not do time calculation?

Comment: I can see this issue even on Android 11. Could it be? Nothing can be done about it? How come it still occurs? Seems it was marked as fixed for Android 11, but I still see it: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/161374959

Comment: I have not been doing any Android Dev work for a while now (2017 was my last project) - so I have no first hand knowledge. I still believe the original observations are still in effect - this is very very hard to fix. It requires the ART GC run to be aware of the cpu "sleep" state.

Comment: the latest AOSP code still uses Thread.sleep to wait for timeout, which is still problematic in the CPU hibernate scenario. Why don't android try to get the thread execution time of FinalizeDaemon, like SystemClock.currentThreadTime but for the FinalizeDaemon. The thread time is managed by the kernel with respect to thread scheduling. https://cs.android.com/android/platform/superproject/+/master:libcore/libart/src/main/java/java/lang/Daemons.java;l=419?q=Daemons

Answer (score 79):

We see this constantly, all over our app, using Crashlytics. The crash usually happens way down in platform code. A small sampling:

> android.database.CursorWindow.finalize() timed out after 10 seconds
>
> java.util.regex.Matcher.finalize() timed out after 10 seconds
>
> android.graphics.Bitmap$BitmapFinalizer.finalize() timed out after 10 seconds
>
> org.apache.http.impl.conn.SingleClientConnManager.finalize() timed out after 10 seconds
>
> java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.finalize() timed out after 10 seconds
>
> android.os.BinderProxy.finalize() timed out after 10 seconds
>
> android.graphics.Path.finalize() timed out after 10 seconds

The devices on which this happens are overwhelmingly (but not exclusively) devices manufactured by Samsung. That could just mean that most of our users are using Samsung devices; alternately it could indicate a problem with Samsung devices. I'm not really sure.

I suppose this doesn't really answer your questions, but I just wanted to reinforce that this seems quite common, and is not specific to your application.

Comment: Its happening for Android 5.0.1 version as well and doesn't seem to be restricted to Samsung devices. It happened on Nexus 6.

Comment: I have this issue on android 4.4.4 with device manufactured by XIAOMI

Comment: Just wanted to chime in that we are seeing the majority of these crashes on samsung tablets.  Not sure what samsung did differently with how tablets handle backgrounded apps.

Comment: Spotted on Android 4 & 5

Comment: i have this issue on android 4.4.4. device manufactured by HUAWEI.

Comment: My app crashes after if I use leak canary library on android 5.0.2 Samsung device. If I disable the library initialization, the app works just fine.

Comment: can we increase timeout caused by java.util.concurrentTimeOut exception?

Comment: In our application, 54% crashes happen in Samsung, it may has something related with Samsung.

Comment: Why in Nexus 5 (v6.0.1) `FATAL EXCEPTION: FinalizerWatchdogDaemon concurrent.TimeoutException: android.media.MediaMetadataRetriever.finalize()`

Comment: Same issues on Android 10. 100% Samsung devices.

Comment: on my project, it happened on Lenovo Tab M10 FHD Plus, android 10

Answer (score 18):

I found some slides about this issue.

http://de.slideshare.net/DroidConTLV/android-crash-analysis-and-the-dalvik-garbage-collector-tools-and-tips

In this slides the author tells that it seems to be a problem with GC, if there are a lot of objects or huge objects in heap. The slide also include a reference to a sample app and a python script to analyze this issue.

https://github.com/oba2cat3/GCTest

https://github.com/oba2cat3/logcat2memorygraph

Furthermore I found a hint in comment #3 on this side: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=53418#c3

Answer (score 12):

Here is an effective solution from didi to solve this problem, Since this bug is very common and difficult to find the cause, It looks more like a system problem, Why can't we ignore it directly？Of course we can ignore it, Here is the sample code:

```java
final Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler defaultUncaughtExceptionHandler = 
        Thread.getDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler();
Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(new Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler() {
    @Override
    public void uncaughtException(Thread t, Throwable e) {
        if (t.getName().equals("FinalizerWatchdogDaemon") && e instanceof TimeoutException) {
        } else {
            defaultUncaughtExceptionHandler.uncaughtException(t, e);
        }
    }
});
```

By setting a special default uncaught exception handler, application can change the way in which uncaught exceptions are handled for those threads that would already accept whatever default behavior the system provided. When an uncaught `TimeoutException` is thrown from a thread named `FinalizerWatchdogDaemon`,  this special handler will block the handler chain, the system handler will not be called, so crash will be avoided.

Through practice, no other bad effects were found. The GC system is still working, timeouts are alleviated as CPU usage decreases.

For more details see: https://mp.weixin.qq.com/s/uFcFYO2GtWWiblotem2bGg

Comment: how to use this to overcome exception?

Comment: Heads up, `defaultUncaughtExceptionHandler` can be null if no default is set

Answer (score 8):

We solved the problem by stopping the `FinalizerWatchdogDaemon`.

```
public static void fix() {
    try {
        Class clazz = Class.forName("java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerWatchdogDaemon");

        Method method = clazz.getSuperclass().getDeclaredMethod("stop");
        method.setAccessible(true);

        Field field = clazz.getDeclaredField("INSTANCE");
        field.setAccessible(true);

        method.invoke(field.get(null));

    }
    catch (Throwable e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

You can call the method in Application's lifecycle, like `attachBaseContext()`.
For the same reason, you also can specific the phone's manufacture to fix the problem, it's up to you.

Comment: Doesn't work for us, I cannot understand why. Code completes without exceptions but we still receive those issues in Crashlytics reports and Google Play Console.

Answer (score 5):

Broadcast Receivers timeout after 10 seconds.  Possibly your doing an asynchronous call (wrong) from a broadcast receiver and 4.3 actually detects it.

Comment: Seems useless to detect it and not tell you enough about it.  Letting us know which broadcast would be nice.

Comment: Pardon if I'm wrong, but I don't think the broadcast receiver timeout causes this particular crash. It's good practice to avoid the 10s limit, but that's a different issue than the requester is having.

Comment: I just have 10 seconds on the brain. http://developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-anr.html IDK if it was causing the crash either.

Comment: Your point is solid and a good practice. However, the original poster has a specific question about a specific set of devices. I'd advise other viewers of this post to check Christopher's answer and oba's answer if they're seeing the same symptoms (Samsung devices (esp. Galaxy S 4), etc.)

Comment: I'm not here to bash device manufactures it would be against the terms.

Answer (score 5):

One thing which is invariably true is that at this time, the device would be suffocating for some memory (which is usually the reason for GC to most likely get triggered).

As mentioned by almost all authors earlier, this issue surfaces when Android tries to run GC while the app is in background. In most of the cases where we observed it, user paused the app by locking their screen.
This might also indicate memory leak somewhere in the application, or the device being too loaded already.
So the only legitimate way to minimize it is:

- to ensure there are no memory leaks, and
- to reduce the memory footprint of the app in general.

Answer (score 1):

```
try {
    Class<?> c = Class.forName("java.lang.Daemons");
    Field maxField = c.getDeclaredField("MAX_FINALIZE_NANOS");
    maxField.setAccessible(true);
    maxField.set(null, Long.MAX_VALUE);
} catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: This will not solve the problem in case the Sleep duration is > 100 seconds. Why not set it to MAX_INT?

Comment: Yes,I'm just do example~

Comment: This should not work because of constant inlining. Changing the field value will not affect the value inlined to callers.

Answer (score 0):

The finalizeQueue may be too long

i think that java may require [GC.SuppressFinalize()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.gc.suppressfinalize(v=vs.110).aspx) & [GC.ReRegisterForFinalize()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.gc.reregisterforfinalize(v=vs.110).aspx) to let user reduce the finalizedQueue length explicitly

if the JVM' source code is available, may implement these method ourself, such as android ROM maker

Answer (score 0):

It seems like a Android Runtime bug. There seems to be finalizer that runs in its separate thread and calls finalize() method on objects if they are not in the current frame of the stacktrace.
For example following code(created to verify this issue) ended with the crash.

Let's have some cursor that do something in finalize method(e.g. SqlCipher ones, do close() which locks to the database that is currently in use)

```
private static class MyCur extends MatrixCursor {


    public MyCur(String[] columnNames) {
        super(columnNames);
    }

    @Override
    protected void finalize() {
        super.finalize();

        try {
            for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
                Thread.sleep(30);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

And we do some long running stuff having opened cursor:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                MyCur cur = null;
                try {
                    cur = new MyCur(new String[]{});
                    longRun();
                } finally {
                    cur.close();
                }
            }

            private void longRun() {
                try {
                    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
                        Thread.sleep(30);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }).start();
    }
```

This causes following error:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: FinalizerWatchdogDaemon
                                                                        Process: la.la.land, PID: 29206
                                                                        java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: MyCur.finalize() timed out after 10 seconds
                                                                            at java.lang.Thread.sleep(Native Method)
                                                                            at java.lang.Thread.sleep(Thread.java:371)
                                                                            at java.lang.Thread.sleep(Thread.java:313)
                                                                            at MyCur.finalize(MessageList.java:1791)
                                                                            at java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerDaemon.doFinalize(Daemons.java:222)
                                                                            at java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerDaemon.run(Daemons.java:209)
                                                                            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:762)
```

The production variant with SqlCipher is very similiar:

```js
12-21 15:40:31.668: E/EH(32131): android.content.ContentResolver$CursorWrapperInner.finalize() timed out after 10 seconds
12-21 15:40:31.668: E/EH(32131): java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: android.content.ContentResolver$CursorWrapperInner.finalize() timed out after 10 seconds
12-21 15:40:31.668: E/EH(32131):  at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
12-21 15:40:31.668: E/EH(32131):  at java.lang.Thread.parkFor$(Thread.java:2128)
12-21 15:40:31.668: E/EH(32131):  at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Unsafe.java:325)
12-21 15:40:31.668: E/EH(32131):  at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:161)
12-21 15:40:31.668: E/EH(32131):  at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.parkAndCheckInterrupt(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:840)
12-21 15:40:31.668: E/EH(32131):  at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.acquireQueued(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:873)
12-21 15:40:31.668: E/EH(32131):  at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.acquire(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:1197)
12-21 15:40:31.668: E/EH(32131):  at java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock$FairSync.lock(ReentrantLock.java:200)
12-21 15:40:31.668: E/EH(32131):  at java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock.lock(ReentrantLock.java:262)
12-21 15:40:31.668: E/EH(32131):  at net.sqlcipher.database.SQLiteDatabase.lock(SourceFile:518)
12-21 15:40:31.668: E/EH(32131):  at net.sqlcipher.database.SQLiteProgram.close(SourceFile:294)
12-21 15:40:31.668: E/EH(32131):  at net.sqlcipher.database.SQLiteQuery.close(SourceFile:136)
12-21 15:40:31.668: E/EH(32131):  at net.sqlcipher.database.SQLiteCursor.close(SourceFile:510)
12-21 15:40:31.668: E/EH(32131):  at android.database.CursorWrapper.close(CursorWrapper.java:50)
12-21 15:40:31.668: E/EH(32131):  at android.database.CursorWrapper.close(CursorWrapper.java:50)
12-21 15:40:31.668: E/EH(32131):  at android.content.ContentResolver$CursorWrapperInner.close(ContentResolver.java:2746)
12-21 15:40:31.668: E/EH(32131):  at android.content.ContentResolver$CursorWrapperInner.finalize(ContentResolver.java:2757)
12-21 15:40:31.668: E/EH(32131):  at java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerDaemon.doFinalize(Daemons.java:222)
12-21 15:40:31.668: E/EH(32131):  at java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerDaemon.run(Daemons.java:209)
12-21 15:40:31.668: E/EH(32131):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:762)
```

Resume: **Close cursors ASAP.** At least on Samsung S8 with Android 7 where the issue have been seen.

Answer (score 0):

For classes that you create (ie. are not part of the Android) its possible to avoid the crash completely.

Any class that implements `finalize()` has some unavoidable probability of crashing as explained by @oba. So instead of using finalizers to perform cleanup, use a `PhantomReferenceQueue`.

For an example check out the implementation in React Native: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/master/ReactAndroid/src/main/java/com/facebook/jni/DestructorThread.java