# android.media.MediaCodec.finalize() timed out after 10 seconds

Tags: android, crash, timeout

```
Fatal Exception: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
android.media.MediaCodec.finalize() timed out after 10 seconds
```

I'm receiving this exception from fabric happened with Samsung Galaxy Note 3 (4.3) on the end users side, anybody has any clue on why it happened?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This crash reported by fabric. This is not related to your Application:

https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=205978

Devices:

- **Samsung (62%) : GT-I9300, SM-G7105, GT-I9500, ...**
- **LG (19%) : Nexus 4, H815, D855**
- **Motorola (15%) : XT1058, XT1060, XT1055,...**
- **others (4%)**

Android versions:

- **Android 5.x : 54%**
- **Android 4.x : 45%**
- **Android 6.x : 1%**

Following link clearly explains.

[How to handle :java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: android.os.BinderProxy.finalize() timed out after 10 seconds errors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24021609/how-to-handle-java-util-concurrent-timeoutexception-android-os-binderproxy-fin)