# What is root cause for android.graphics.Path.finalize() timed out after 10 seconds

Tags: android

> Fatal Exception: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException:
>   android.graphics.Path.finalize() timed out after 10 seconds
>          at android.graphics.Path.finalizer(Path.java)
>          at android.graphics.Path.finalize(Path.java:748)
>          at java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerDaemon.doFinalize(Daemons.java:202)
>          at java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerDaemon.run(Daemons.java:185)
>          at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)

I am getting this error in one of my live app, I tried all the way possible to figure this out still no results. It would really awesome if somebody could tell me about this issue in detail & ways to fix it. Thanks in advance.

Edit:

I found few more logs:

> ```
>    at android.view.GLES20Canvas.nDrawBitmap(GLES20Canvas.java)
>    at android.view.GLES20Canvas.drawBitmap(GLES20Canvas.java:614)
>    at android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable.draw(BitmapDrawable.java:545)
>    at android.widget.ImageView.onDraw(ImageView.java:1197)
>    at com.flaviofaria.kenburnsview.KenBurnsView.onDraw(SourceFile:201)
>    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:16536)
>    at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:15466)
>    at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:15488)
>    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:16258)
>    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3713)
>    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3506)
>    at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:15461)
>    at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:15488)
>    at android.view.ViewGroup.recreateChildDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3697)
>    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3676)
>    at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:15426)
>    at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:15488)
>    at android.view.ViewGroup.recreateChildDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3697)
>    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3676)
>    at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:15426)
>    at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:15488)
>    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:16258)
>    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3713)
>    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3506)
>    at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:15461)
>    at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:15488)
>    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:16258)
>    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3713)
>    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3506)
>    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:16539)
>    at android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:598)
>    at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:15466)
>    at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:15488)
>    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:16258)
>    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3713)
>    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3506)
>    at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:15461)
>    at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:15488)
>    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:16258)
>    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3713)
>    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3506)
>    at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:15461)
>    at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:15488)
>    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:16258)
>    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3713)
>    at com.shaiban.audioplayer.mplayer.slidinguppanel.SlidingUpPanelLayout.drawChild(SourceFile:964)
>    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3506)
>    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:16539)
>    at com.shaiban.audioplayer.mplayer.slidinguppanel.SlidingUpPanelLayout.draw(SourceFile:1013)
>    at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:15466)
>    at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:15488)
>    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:16258)
>    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3713)
>    at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.drawChild(SourceFile:1377)
>    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3506)
>    at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:15461)
>    at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:15488)
>    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:16258)
>    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3713)
>    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3506)
>    at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:15461)
>    at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:15488)
>    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:16258)
>    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3713)
>    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3506)
>    at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:15461)
>    at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:15488)
>    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:16258)
>    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3713)
>    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3506)
>    at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:15461)
>    at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:15488)
>    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:16258)
>    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3713)
>    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3506)
>    at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:15461)
>    at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:15488)
>    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:16258)
>    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3713)
>    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3506)
>    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:16539)
>    at android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:598)
>    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.draw(PhoneWindow.java:3111)
>    at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:15466)
>    at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:15488)
>    at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.updateViewTreeDisplayList(ThreadedRenderer.java:309)
>    at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.updateRootDisplayList(ThreadedRenderer.java:315)
>    at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.draw(ThreadedRenderer.java:354)
>    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.draw(ViewRootImpl.java:2956)
>    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performDraw(ViewRootImpl.java:2753)
>    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2339)
>    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1314)
>    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:7057)
>    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:829)
>    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:606)
>    at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:576)
>    at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:815)
>    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
>    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
>    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7007)
>    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
>    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
>    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1404)
>    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1199)
> ```

Comment: It means the finalizer for the object took too long.  Either its truly huge, or there's some reason the thread was paused-  possibly deadlock.

Comment: Thank you for quick response. Any idea How to detect which part of code is causing this ? Because with logs i see only above stacktrace and no origin from the app code is mentioned.

Comment: Its origin is the garbage collector.  Finalize is roughly like a destructor, but with no promise of when/if it will be called.  Its called just before an object is memory collected.

Comment: You may want to check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24021609/how-to-handle-java-util-concurrent-timeoutexception-android-os-binderproxy-fin

Comment: Ok. How to fix this issue ?

Answer (score 0):

OK - Here is my answer:
Protected method finalize is called by the garbage collector on an object when garbage collection determines that there are no more references to the object.
A subclass overrides the finalize method to dispose of system resources or to perform other cleanup.
as it is in [Google Developer Documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Path.html#finalize())

As a matter of fact I have the same problem in my app which draws hundreds of paths in second :
see [Visual Sounds Music Visualizer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.julian.visualsounds)
and my Google Play Console statistics say that it is only with Android 5.1

```
java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: 
1. at android.graphics.Path.finalizer (Native Method)
2. at android.graphics.Path.finalize (Path.java:748)
3. at java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerDaemon.doFinalize (Daemons.java:206)
4. at java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerDaemon.run (Daemons.java:189)
5. at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:818)
```