# CrashlyticsCore: Failed to execute task. java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException

Tags: android, android-studio

> CrashlyticsCore: Failed to execute task.
>                                                                      java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
>                                                                          at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:176)
>                                                                          at
>   com.crashlytics.android.core.CrashlyticsBackgroundWorker.submitAndWait(CrashlyticsBackgroundWorker.java:41)
>                                                                          at
>   com.crashlytics.android.core.CrashlyticsController.handleUncaughtException(CrashlyticsController.java:285)
>                                                                          at
>   com.crashlytics.android.core.CrashlyticsController$5.onUncaughtException(CrashlyticsController.java:269)
>                                                                          at
>   com.crashlytics.android.core.CrashlyticsUncaughtExceptionHandler.uncaughtException(CrashlyticsUncaughtExceptionHandler.java:30)
>                                                                          at java.lang.ThreadGroup.uncaughtException(ThreadGroup.java:693)
>                                                                          at java.lang.ThreadGroup.uncaughtException(ThreadGroup.java:690)
>                                                                          at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Comment: Where is the question?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to handle :java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: android.os.BinderProxy.finalize() timed out after 10 seconds errors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24021609/how-to-handle-java-util-concurrent-timeoutexception-android-os-binderproxy-fin)

Comment: @LevonPetrosyan I don't think they are the same.